# Seria apropriado utilizar o stackoverflow como meio para comprovar algo?

Tags: debate, suporte

Realizei essa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/412191/devo-usar-bibliotecas-de-frameworks-para-desenvolver-uma-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-segura-para-g?noredirect=1#comment804542_412191), que seria identificada como "Principalmente baseada em opiniões". Estou arrumando meios para poder comprovar para meus colegas de trabalho de quais formas seriam melhores para aplicarmos em nosso sitema. E para isso tentei utilizar o ***stackoverflow***. Tentando me basear no conhecimento de pessoas experientes no assunto. Seria adequado fazer isso?

Comment: Se é baseada em opinião, então sua pergunta já foi respondida: não. Você pode utilizar o [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) para tal.

Comment: Ao que tudo indica parece ser baseado em opiniões mesmo, basta ver os comentários. Para comprovar algo pode ser apropriado, o problema é que parece que a pergunta pede opinião e não algo que pode ser comprovado. Então ela quer uma opinião que faça de conta que seja uma comprovação. Perigoso, né? OU seja, ela pede uma *fake news*, considerando que *fake news* é alguém falar alguma coisa para ser usada como validação de um pensamento que já se tem, então pode usar com outras pessoas afirmando que não é só sua opinião, é de outras pessoas também, e...

Comment: ... a tese seria que se outras pessoas tem a mesma opinião então é o certo. Então pode-se ir em um fórum de terraplanistas e obter a validação que deseja e usar isso como comprovação que está certo.

Comment: Eu justamente me mantive nos comentários por isso. Simplesmente deixei minha opinião (só com PHP já são mais de 2 décadas de experiência, mas ainda assim é um ponto de vista específico), mas nao poderia usar o campo de respostas mesmo assim. Claro que eu procurei não entrar na parte do Laravel para evitar magoar alguns egos, mas também acho que o chat é o único espaço que essa discussão caberia. E aí talvez fique bem construtiva, inclusive, pois abre espaço para o confronto saudável de idéias.

Comment: @Bacco «Claro que eu procurei não entrar na parte do Laravel para evitar magoar alguns egos...» ahahahahah

Comment: Para quem puder me ajudar, eu criei uma sala https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99056/laravel-ou-php-para-seguranca

Comment: @ArthurAbitante talvez seja bom até usar a sala "Estouro de Pilha", pq ai pega um movimento maior. O problema de uma só pra isso é que dificilmente coincide de entrar todo mundo interessado só naquele tópico ao mesmo tempo (mas nada impede de manter essa, claro)

Comment: @Maniero, gostei da maneira de pensar. Eu primeiramente pretendo obter a opinião de pessoas que possuem experiência no assunto. E também tentar observar os varios outros pontos de vistas. Pessoas como o senhor e o  Bacco como exemplo, são possiveis bases para mim onde posso obter uma informação onde eu posso confiar. E como estou iniciando na carreira de desenvolvimento, estou em uma fase de bastante duvidas. Sempre tento fazer o "bem feito", mas acabo em outras situações que dão mais duvidas ainda de como fazer.

Comment: @Bacco, ok, agradeço pela a ajuda!!!

Comment: Você quer confiar em *fake news*, ninguém está acima de qualquer suspeita, todo mundo tem seu *bias*. Algumas coisas não são objetivas por mais que queira que sejam. E informações subjetivas tem dificuldade de sobreviver bem.

Comment: @ArthurAbitante a melhor forma de aprender é errar. Eu quando comecei fazia muitas coisas que hoje vou ver e até tenho vergonha eheheh. Eu quando é assim tento pedir opiniões no chat. Mas como são só opiniões eu pego e vou testar e pesquisar sobre a opinião que recebi. Ainda estes dias o Bacco aconselhou-me o fpdf, eu fui pesquisar sobre, ver a API, etc e de seguida testei. Então percebi que era o ideal para o que eu estava a fazer. Mas antes já tinha experimentado outros. Errar para aprender não tem nada de mal, de certeza que o Bacco não nasceu ensinado ;)